# Why does the scheduler fail on the first 3 or 4 times I run it?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-scheduler

I have a Cloud Function running on Google Cloud with HTTP trigger.
The trigger works fine and the function as well but I am getting errors to execute it via Google Scheduler.
The function connect to Cloud SQL and insert and retrieve information from the database:
Here is the function:

```
from os import getenv
import requests
import pymysql
import json
from pymysql.err import OperationalError

# TODO(developer): specify SQL connection details
CONNECTION_NAME = getenv('INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME', 'name')
DB_USER = getenv('MYSQL_USER', 'root')
DB_PASSWORD = getenv('MYSQL_PASSWORD', 'password')
DB_NAME = getenv('MYSQL_DATABASE', 'dbName')

mysql_config = {
  'user': DB_USER,
  'password': DB_PASSWORD,
  'db': DB_NAME,
  'charset': 'utf8mb4',
  'cursorclass': pymysql.cursors.DictCursor,
  'autocommit': True
}

# Create SQL connection globally to enable reuse
# PyMySQL does not include support for connection pooling
mysql_conn = None


def __get_cursor():
    """
    Helper function to get a cursor
      PyMySQL does NOT automatically reconnect,
      so we must reconnect explicitly using ping()
    """
    try:
        return mysql_conn.cursor()
    except OperationalError:
        mysql_conn.ping(reconnect=True)
        return mysql_conn.cursor()


def authMonzo(request):
    global mysql_conn
    global endpoint

    endpoint = 'https://****/oauth2/token'

    # Initialize connections lazily, in case SQL access isn't needed for this
    # GCF instance. Doing so minimizes the number of active SQL connections,
    # which helps keep your GCF instances under SQL connection limits.
    if not mysql_conn:
        try:
            mysql_conn = pymysql.connect(**mysql_config)
        except OperationalError:
            # If production settings fail, use local development ones
            mysql_config['unix_socket'] = f'/cloudsql/{CONNECTION_NAME}'
            mysql_conn = pymysql.connect(**mysql_config)

    # Remember to close SQL resources declared while running this function.
    # Keep any declared in global scope (e.g. mysql_conn) for later reuse.
    with __get_cursor() as cursor:   
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM TOKENS ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1")
        result = cursor.fetchall()

        clientSecret = result[len(result) - 1]['CLIENT_SECRET']
        clientId = result[len(result) - 1]['CLIENT_ID']
        refreshToken = result[len(result) - 1]['REFRESH_TOKEN']

        # Change the last refresh token for a new access token
        tokenRequest = requests.post(endpoint, data={'grant_type': 'refresh_token', 'client_id': clientId, 'client_secret': clientSecret, 'refresh_token': refreshToken})
        tokenJson = json.loads(tokenRequest.content)

        print(tokenJson)

        # Assing the values to variables
        accessToken = tokenJson['access_token']
        refreshToken = tokenJson['refresh_token']
        scope = tokenJson['scope']
        clientId = tokenJson['client_id']
        expiresIn = tokenJson['expires_in']
        userId = tokenJson['user_id']
        tokenType = tokenJson['token_type']

        # Insert the new token on the table tokens
        SQLToken = ("INSERT INTO TOKENS (CLIENT_SECRET, ACCESS_TOKEN, REFRESH_TOKEN, TOKEN_TYPE, USER_ID, CLIENT_ID, EXPIRES_IN, SCOPE) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)")
        Values = (clientSecret, accessToken, refreshToken, tokenType, userId, clientId, expiresIn, scope)

        # Insert new account information
        cursor.execute(SQLToken, Values)

    return str(accessToken)
```

After try more than 3 or 4 times I got the `Success` status for the execution.

Follow the Json extracted from the log:

```
 {
 insertId: "000000-dca60f91-5c0f-439f-b21c-bda99114ddce"  

labels: {
  execution_id: ""   
 }
 logName: "projects/quidsave-237317/logs/cloudfunctions.googleapis.com%2Fcloud-functions"  
 receiveTimestamp: "2019-05-02T12:15:55.145395087Z"  

resource: {

labels: {
   function_name: "authMonzo"    
   project_id: "quidsave-237317"    
   region: "europe-west2"    
  }
  type: "cloud_function"   
 }
 severity: "ERROR"  
 textPayload: "Error: function crashed. Function invocation was interrupted.
"  
 timestamp: "2019-05-02T12:15:48.766445135Z"  
}
```

This is the error:

```
severity: "ERROR"  
 textPayload: "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/functions/worker.py", line 346, in run_http_function
    result = _function_handler.invoke_user_function(flask.request)
  File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/functions/worker.py", line 217, in invoke_user_function
    return call_user_function(request_or_event)
  File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/functions/worker.py", line 210, in call_user_function
    return self._user_function(request_or_event)
  File "/user_code/main.py", line 60, in authMonzo
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM TOKENS ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1")
  File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 170, in execute
    result = self._query(query)
  File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 328, in _query
    conn.query(q)
  File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 516, in query
    self._execute_command(COMMAND.COM_QUERY, sql)
  File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 750, in _execute_command
    raise err.InterfaceError("(0, '')")
pymysql.err.InterfaceError: (0, '')
```

Comment: This line is failing `cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM TOKENS ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1")`. You are not detecting / processing errors so your code just crashes.

Comment: Is something wrong with the Cloud SQL. This error appears on the Cloud SQL log: `Aborted connection 14541 to db: 'dbName' user: 'root' host: 'cloudsqlproxy~**.***.**.***' (Got timeout reading communication packets)"`